# xfce4-terminal annoying bottom and right border

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I've just encountered an annoying visual problem - there is a pretty thick bottom and thin right border in `xfce4-terminal`. I guess I didn't notice it before because I was using visually non-enchanted editors before. The problem can be clearly seen when, for example, using `vim` themes. It is not so oblivious when using out-of-the-box `nano` but the border / margin is still there.

Is there a way to remove the border?

A related screenshot (teal bottom and right border)

[image]

Comment: Not sure about the bottom, but the right side appears to be a scrollbar, which can be disabled in the terminal preferences

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue just today. Happens only when I maximize the terminal window. "Solved" it by just setting my terminal background color the same as the one from my vim theme...

See [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/3op358/how_can_i_get_rid_of_this_black_border_in_vim/:):

> Vim can only paint the background by printing characters which is why it can't change the color of the left over space - it's too short to fit any characters.

<s>I still dont get why it only happens in fullscreen and not like every 9 of 10 pixels, though.</s>

I'm stupid; This is because the terminal app does not resize per pixel but per character. So of course manual resizing never brings a border.
But this also means, you could simply fix this problem by choosing a bigger/smaller font in your terminal app, where your screen resolution is a real multiple of the character width.

Also:

> Try this in your vimrc after your theme is loaded, works for jellybean at least:

```
hi Normal ctermbg=none
```

Might make some other trouble, but you could give it a try.